# Technique: remove background by combining two images?

Tags: editing

I have two videos - both are on a tripod, so they are locked in place. First video has an **empty background** (no people or objects), the second video has a **person walking** through the scene.

Is there a technique that allows me to combine the two images - have the empty background remove the background from the person walking through it - and **only keep the person with a transparent background**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the effect you're after is `Difference Matte`. Keep in mind your clean plate needs to be **exactly** the same, pixel for pixel, as in your shots. You'll likely need to do some manual clean up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand but I think you need to grab a video composer like After Effects or Sony Vegas Pro and put the video with the person ontop of the other video. You can achieve clones by that!